# Show only some files in directory listing with NGINX

Tags: nginx

I finally figured out how to show a directory listing of a folder using nginx. 
The problem is that it shows every file and directory in that folder. Is it possible to filter the results? Like show only files with a specific extension or something like that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the [auto-index feature](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) does not support filtering. But you can change permissions of the files to not be visible/served, but that only works if you dont want them accessible at all.

You could try to manually [modify the body response with sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) using regexp that matches files to hide.